# Symfony 1.4 with multiple apps and different databases

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, multiple-databases

I have an important Symfony project, in which I have different apps.
I'd like to have different databases, one for each apps.

I've find that I can have multiple database connections, but when I create schema, models forms and filters symfony put all these classes into /lib/folder.

Is there a way for create models, forms, filters for each application based on his own schema, and put the resulting classes into somthing like /apps/myApp/lib?

Thankyou very much...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "package" parameter in your schema like so:

```
Model:
  connection:                           doctrine
  package:                              your_package
  tableName:                            model
  columns:
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, ok, but this separate only the Model classes, and not filters and forms. However it's not exactly the solutions I'd want. I'd like have many apps, each one with its own forlder. And if were possible, a schema.yml file for every one...